# New Google Maps Marker

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone know the URL to this icon, and if you can change the color on the most recent version of Google Maps API ?

I'd like a blue/green icon like below!

[image]

**EDIT -----------------------------------------**

I've found the markers here:

## Markers With Text

[image: Green Marker]
[image: Red Marker]

```
scale = 2
text  = AB
psize = 16
```

1. [Green Marker](http://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a.png)
2. [Red Marker](http://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-b.png)
3. [Google Development: Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

Comment: What do you mean by `URL to this icon`?  can you add more details?

Comment: From what i can tell, on Google Maps API V2 there was a repository of available icons, that is now deprecated. Mostly of Flat icons with black outlines, that look old as hell now. I'm looking for the nice new ones.

Comment: @Matt Did you manage to find them?

Comment: Gosh, it's a long time ago mate, i can't remember off the top of my head. I will look into it, and if i find something i will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can custom everything with the API of google map.
To have a different pointer, you must add a specific code and give him the link to the icon you want to assign, and its position.

Something like this for exemple:

```
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png'
});
```

---

Link to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

I hope it will be able to help you :)

Comment: I've had a good look at the documentation but cant find a page where i can see what icons are available (from the new google map design). Any ideas if i can view the base shapes anywhere ?

Comment: Why not create your own icon ?

Comment: I have for now, but i know there is a green one already there by google. When u get directions on the new maps, u get the green icon. See edited pic in original question